# MDI child form not staying open

Tags: c#, autofac, mdi

I am trying to get a MDI child form to show when I click on a menu strip item

```
MDIParent1 parent = new MDIParent1();
public void NewForm(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 childForm = new Form3();
    childForm.Show();
    childForm.MdiParent = parent.Parent;
    childForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
}
```

The form is in its own Class Library if I don't set the MDIParent the form loads up and stays up when i set the parent it shows for a split second then it's gone.

I am using AutoFac to build my menu items based on [Dynamic menu creation IoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240838/dynamic-menu-creation-ioc) but unable to get this to work. 
I have this in my main form which should then get the correct MDIParent in.

```
public MDIParent1 Parent
{
   get 
     { 
        return this; 
     }
}
```

Hope someone can figure out where I am going wrong.

Aidan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after some trial and error.

in the IMenuContainer I had to add

```
MDIParent1 Parent { get; }
```

And then in my ClassMenuBuilder I had to

```
 MDIParent1 parent = new MDIParent1();
 public void BuildMenu(IMenuContainer container)
 {
    parent = container.Parent;
 } 

 public void NewForm(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
    Form3 childForm = new Form3();
    childForm.MdiParent = parent.Parent;
    childForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    childForm.Show();
 }
```

Now when I click the Form3 open button it opens the form in the MDIParent.

Hope this helps someone else out.

Aidan