# how to add custom configSections to app.config file through code

Tags: c#, winforms, autofac

How can I add sections to an app.config file through code?

Something like this in my config file, but it can have multiple sections but not through appSettings as I would like to add multiple values to it.

```
<configSections>
 <!-- CUSTOM CONFIG SECTIONS BELOW -->
 <section name="EmailSection" type="Email.EmailSection, Email" />
</configSections>

<EmailSection>
 <Emails>
  <email id="HOST" name="mail.somedomain.com" />
  <email id="PORT" name="25" />
  <email id="TOADDRESS" name="" />
  <email id="FROMADDRESS" name="dev@somedomain.com" />
 </Emails>
</EmailSection>
```

I would like to do this through an import method in my code so i can select an xml file which will then add the sections to my app.config.

Regards

Aidan

Comment: Precise if you want ot do it at runtime or as a kind a tool inside visual studio (or both if you are interested in both) and yes it is more clear (will remove previous comments now).

Comment: I don't see anything to do with Autofac here. Is the tag appropriate? If so, can you explain how Autofac ties in here? If not, can we remove it?

Comment: I am using AutoFac to load in my dll's as per this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240838/dynamic-menu-creation-ioc) so didn't know if there is a way to do it through here sorry should have added the link for further detail.

Comment: Do you really need to write to the app.config file? I think a better practice would be to generate a custom config file in e.g. XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working through [this](http://yizeng.me/2013/08/31/update-appsettings-and-custom-configuration-sections-in-appconfig-at-runtime/).

I had to loop through my items and add them in, but does what I need it.

Thanks for the advice though.

Aidan